# WPF How to correctly serialize UIElement?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I found that when copying WPF InlineUIContainer to clipboard, its UIElement (e.g. Checkbox) gets incorrectly translated to Run. Per this [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e1d6f650-e502-44a9-a239-fb3778c6c5fe/richtextbox-limitation-2-cannot-copypaste-user-controls?forum=wpf) thread, non-Image UIElements are dropped.

What is the code to correctly copy multiple UIElement XAMLs, so they could be pasted in any WPF RichTextBox ? (User can

Here is a debuggable snippet. Add a RichTextBox to your xaml and name it myRichTextBox.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(myRichTextBox, onCopy);
    DataObject.AddPastingHandler(myRichTextBox, onPaste);
}

private void onCopy(object sender, DataObjectCopyingEventArgs e)
{
    Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Xaml, e.DataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Xaml)); //Saved as <Checkbox>
    e.Handled = true;
    e.CancelCommand();
}

private void onPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    object xaml = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Xaml); //Loaded as <Run>
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't do that. you really should just copy enough state to the clipboard and recreate them/move as needed.

Comment: Daniel, I dont get what you mean. Please elaborate ?

Comment: `UIElements` can't be just moved like that. there is a lot of information associated with them and countless references.

Comment: Inside WPF Richtextbox, I need to be able to cut-paste Checkboxes and Textboxes. The problem is, clipboard pasted all of them as Run. If you have a solution or a workaround, please kindly share your code.